# How to change all array while updating one element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to have always only one element `true` in array.

Supposed I have an array

```
let data = [
  { letter: "a", id: 1, bool: false },
  { letter: "b", id: 2, bool: false },
  { letter: "c", id: 3, bool: false},
  { letter: "d", id: 4, bool: false },
];
```

every time I click on an element I need to change it to `true` while all other to `false`.
I have a function

```
const updatedArray = data.map((item) => {
  if (item.id === id) {
    return {
      ...item,
      bool: true,
    };
  }
  return item;
});
```

But it works as a toggle for clicked element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here: `return item;`,you are actually returning the previous value and just updating the `bool` property of item which has the same id as `id` variable, but you need to toggle the `bool` property of all the items, you can acheive your goal like this:

```
const updatedArray = array.map((item) => ({...item, bool: item.id === id}));
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to also set the item's `bool` to false if it is not the selected item, not just set the selected item's `bool` to true. This should work:

```
const id = 3 (clicked item)
const updatedArray = array.map(item => {
  if (item.id === id) {
    return {
      ...item,
      bool: true
    };
  }
  return {
    ...item,
    bool: false
  }
});
```

Comment: Please be DRY - There is NEVER a reason to use `IF` to set a bool

Comment: I just modified the OP's code.